# Prevent people sharing my Facebook business page's posts

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

Is there any way to prevent people from sharing posts of my Facebook **business** **page**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pages are public spaces, so they're visible to everyone. Anyone can view and share, even banned people are able to view and share posts from your Page on their own timeline (but banned people can't interact with your posts through comments or likes).

As of now there in no official way to prevent people to share post from the page.

Comment: Thanks. But I think it should be changed, at least for the banned users. They should not be allowed to view/share.

Comment: You can send your [feedback](https://www.facebook.com/help/127103474099499) to Facebook.